# Error - Creating default object from empty value in Kohana 2.3.5

Tags: php, view, kohana

I try use in controler:

```
public function add_sms() {

    $this->request->response = View::factory( 'backend/sms/add_sms' );

}
```

Routing is ok, but if i can try to enter link i have error:

> ERROR
>   Creating default object from empty value
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/strefa-partnera/modules/sms/controllers/sms.php [23]:

23 line: `$this->request->response = View::factory( 'backend/sms/add_sms');`

pastebin: `http://pastebin.com/2deiCUpq`

so my problem is that the view does not work because of this exception.

Comment: Could you please explain it better so that one can be more precise with solution and understands your problem.

Comment: how i can create view in kohana 2.3.5? i try use response in controler:
$this->request->response = View::factory( 'backend/sms/add_sms' );

i have view in backend/sms/add_sms.php:
<p>test page</p>

but i have error: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: look on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/2deiCUpq

Answer (score 0):

Check `$this->request`.

This error is thrown when:

```
$obj= NULL;
$obj->attr = 'some';
```